# Cast the value of a string to enum class variable

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, xaml, mvvm

I want to assign a string value got from a restful API to my Designation value which is an "enum" class variable.I was trying to do it like this but it's not working I guess.Can somebody please tell me how to do it correctly?
People.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ISTE.Models
{
    public enum Designation
    {
        Lecturer,
        Professor
    }
    public class Faculty
    {
        public BitmapImage _image;
        public Uri _IconUri;
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tagline { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        public Uri IconUri
        {
            get;

            set; }

        public BitmapImage image { get; set; }


        public string title { get; set; }
        public string interestArea { get; set; }
        public string office { get; set; }
        public Uri website { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string twitter { get; set; }
        public string facebook { get; set; }
        public Designation desig { get; set; }
    }

    public class Staff
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tagline { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string interestArea { get; set; }
        public string office { get; set; }
        public Uri website { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string twitter { get; set; }
        public string facebook { get; set; }
    }


    public class People
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string subTitle { get; set; }
        public List<Faculty> faculty { get; set; }
        public List<Staff> staff { get; set; }

    }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataService

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ISTE.Models;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ISTE.Services
{
    public class PeopleDS
    {
        public List<Faculty> GetItemDetails()
        {
            People facItem = new People();
            Faculty fa = new Faculty();

            List < Faculty > fac = new List<Faculty>();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Key", "9ef8ddfc6d254dc3a7b2cac337c6d837");
                    string uri3 = $"https://ist.xyz.edu/api/people";

                    var response1 = client.GetAsync(uri3).Result;
                    var content1 = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    dynamic item1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content1);
                    facItem.faculty = item1.faculty.ToObject<List<Faculty>>();

                    fac = item1.faculty.ToObject<List<Faculty>>();

                    foreach (Faculty fy in fac)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("designation \t" + fy.title);
                        fy.desig = (Designation)Enum.Parse(typeof(Designation), fy.title, true);

                        // try to parse the string as a TestEnum without throwing an exception
                        var designation = fy.desig;
                        if (Enum.TryParse(fy.title, true, out designation))
                        {
                            // success
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // the string isn't an element of TestEnum
                        }

// ...


                        fy.imagePath = fy.imagePath;
                        fy.IconUri = new Uri(fy.imagePath);
                        fy.image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(fy.IconUri);
                    }




                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return fac;
            }
            return fac;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code, and very little of it is pertinent to your question. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. As a general rule, your question should not only apply to you but to anyone who might face a similar problem to yours.

Comment: Also, please describe how it's "not working". Are you getting an exception? If so, please show it, and on which line. Is the value not getting set to what you expect? If so, please state the input, the output, and what you expected instead of what you got.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about something like this, off the top of my head and untested:

```
 Designation designation = (Designation) Enum.Parse(typeof(Designation), designationString);
```

You would want to add error trapping or perhaps use Enum.TryParse instead and let that trap exceptions for you...

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, having dug through the code which as @Sty said was way too much for the question it seems he has attempted to do that using TryParse.  The question was how to do it correctly, and in my view my answer meets that requirement.  I am not in a position to test the rest of his code to look for some other error which has not even been described, so the best I could do was answer the question that was asked to the best of my ability...

Comment: Yeah, I understand. His code already uses both `Parse` and `TryParse`. I guess my point is that his question is fairly unclear, which makes answering it almost impossible...

Comment: What I can understand is If the string title is having space like "Assistant Professor" it's not able to parse it, while I am able to parse single words like "Professor" , "Lecturer"... any solution? will b highly appreciated...

Comment: Enum keys cannot contain spaces.  Therefore it is not possible to parse "Assistant Professor" as it can never produce a valid result.  This leaves two choices - either use the correct text as the starting point of your parse (e.g. modify wherever you get the string from to return the correct string value), or perhaps remove the spaces if that gives a valid string.  If you have Description attributes that include the spaces, you could also iterate the descriptions looking for a match and return the value if found.

Comment: Thanks @old its working now...I removed the spaces from the string retrieved and then used TryParse

Answer (score -1):

To cast a string to an enum, you can do this:

```
SomeEnum bar;
if (Enum.TryParse(incoming, true, out bar))
{
    // parsing succeeded
}
```

Comment: @RufusL Hmmm. Yes, having dug through the code which as Sty said was way too much for the question it seems he has attempted to do that using TryParse. The question was how to do it correctly, and in my view my answer meets that requirement. I am not in a position to test the rest of his code to look for some other error which has not even been described, so the best I could do was answer the question that was asked to the best of my ability.

Comment: Sorry guys I am new to stackoverflow and not so perfect in asking precise questions.I will still try my level best in future to ask in a crisp manner...

Comment: Here the thing is that I am getting the value of string title which is a property of class Faculty from the API which is either "lecturer" or "Professor", I am trying to assign this value to Designation type variable desig (Designation is enum).I am trying to cast the value of fy.title to fy.desig .

Comment: @Sikha so what is the problem? Are you getting an error? exception?

Comment: yes there was an exception but I got it now why...it was because there were other titles as well other than "Lecturer" and "Professor" so when it was getting those values it was throwing error, I added them too in Designation enum declaration,now its working fine...Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: @CodingYoshi - why is your comment a verbatim reproduction of my comment of an hour earlier?

Comment: @oldcoder yes because your reply was spot on to rufus and he made the same comment to my answer so I figured to tell him the exact thing :)